# Pandastable table not showing inside method

Tags: python, pandas

```
from pandastable import Table
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3],
                   'b': [4, 5, 6]})

class DataTable(tk.Frame):
    """Basic frame for the Table"""
    def __init__(self, *args, df=None, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.main = self.master
        f = tk.Frame(self.main)
        f.pack(fill=tk.BOTH,expand=1)
        self.table = pt = Table(
            f, dataframe=df,
            showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)
        pt.show()
        
def new_window():
    root1 = tk.Tk()
    root1.geometry('600x400')
    frame11 = tk.Frame(root1)
    frame11.pack()
    
    frame12 = DataTable(frame11, df=df)
    frame12.pack()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x400')
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

frame1 = tk.Frame(frame)
frame1.pack()
button = tk.Button(frame1, text='Click Me', command=new_window)
button.pack()

frame2 = DataTable(frame, df=df)
frame2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The `root` window shows the table like I want. The `root1` window appears when I press the button, but no table shows. How do I get the table to show in `root1`?

**Edit:** The table is showing below the table from the first frame, in the same frame. You have to expand the window to see this. I need the second table in the second frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use tk's `Toplevel` class:

```
from pandastable import Table
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3],
                   'b': [4, 5, 6]})
        
def new_window():
    global window
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    window.geometry('600x400')
    frame2 = tk.Frame(window)
    frame2.pack()
    
    table2 = Table(frame2, dataframe=df+10,
                   showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)
    table2.show()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x400')
frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame1.pack()

frame1a = tk.Frame(frame1)
frame1a.pack()
button = tk.Button(frame1a, text='Click Me', command=new_window)
button.pack()

frame1b = tk.Frame(frame1)
frame1b.pack()
table1 = Table(frame1b, dataframe=df,
               showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)
table1.show()

root.mainloop()
```

I made the second dataframe `df+10` to emphasize that it was different from the first.